# как сделать border bottom длиной как текст?

Tags: html, css

[image: галерея]

HTML

```
     <dl>
      <dt class="option">Описание:</dt>
      <dd class="def">холст/масло</dd>
      <dt class="option">Размер:</dt>
      <dd class="def">28см x 40см</dd>
      <dt class="option">Год:</dt>
      <dd class="def">2017</dd>
      <dt class="option">Цена:</dt>
      <dd class="def">100500</dd>
    </dl>
```

CSS

```
.option {
  font-family: 'verdana';
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border-bottom: @orange 1px solid;
  }

.def{
font-family: 'verdana';
font-size: 1.2em;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: оберните текст в `span` и дайте ему border-bottom

Answer (score 4):

Если вам нужно, чтобы подчеркивание было одно в случае, если описание будет больше, чем одна строчка, то можно использовать float:

```css
 dl,dt,dd{
   padding:0;
   marfin:0;
   display:block;
 }
 .option {
  text-align:right;
  float:right;
  border-bottom:1px solid orange;
 }

.def{
  clear:both;
  text-align:right;
  margin-bottom:30px
 }
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt class="option">Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание:</dt>
  <dd class="def">холст/масло</dd>
  <dt class="option">Размер:</dt>
  <dd class="def">28см x 40см</dd>
  <dt class="option">Год:</dt>
  <dd class="def">2017</dd>
  <dt class="option">Цена:</dt>
  <dd class="def">100500</dd>
</dl>
```

Если нет, то можно использовать span:

```css
 dl,dt,dd{
   padding:0;
   marfin:0;
   display:block;
 }
 .option {
  text-align:right;
 }
 .option span{
  border-bottom:1px solid orange;
 }

.def{
  text-align:right;
  margin-bottom:30px
 }
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt class="option"><span>Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание:</span></dt>
  <dd class="def">холст/масло</dd>
  <dt class="option"><span>Размер:</span></dt>
  <dd class="def">28см x 40см</dd>
  <dt class="option"><span>Год:</span></dt>
  <dd class="def">2017</dd>
  <dt class="option"><span>Цена:</span></dt>
  <dd class="def">100500</dd>
</dl>
```